# Area enclosed between $2$ curves

Tags: derivatives, curves

> Question: The area enclosed by the curves $$ y^2 = x \ \text{and} \ y^2 = \ 3x - 1, \ \ \ \ \  \text{where} \  \ 0\leq \  x\leq \frac{1}{2} \ $$

My work:

To begin with I re-arranged the curves in terms of $y$ to the power $1$
$$y_{1} = \sqrt{x}$$

and

$$y_{2} = \sqrt{3x-1}$$

and then proceeded to take the integral for both over the interval $0\leq \  x\leq \frac{1}{2}$
$$f(x_{1}) = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}}$$

and
$$f(x_{2}) = \frac{5^{\frac{3}{2}}}{9\sqrt{2}} - \frac{2}{9}$$

And therefore the area between the curves is $\displaystyle\int f(x_{1}) - f(x_{2})$ right?

Is this the correct method? Because the answer that was provided to me was $\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9}$.

Comment: What are that $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: At $x<1/3$, $y^2=3x-1<0$, so $y$ is complex. Are you sure you have the problem correctly typed?

Comment: The inequality is right?

Comment: @ArcticChar just differentiating between both functions.

Comment: @Andrei yes I checked again. The question is as given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $A_1$ is area between parabola $y^2 = x$ and line $x = \frac{1}{2}$, which you write as $f(x_1)$ and $A_2$ is the area between parabola $y^2 = 3x-1$ and line $x = \frac{1}{2}$

You need to multiple $A_1$ by $2$ as the answer you have is only upper / lower half of the area.

Coming to $A_2$, your mistake is that you are integrating between $x = 0$ and $x = \frac{1}{2}$. The vertex of the second parabola is $(\frac{1}{3}, 0)$. So, you should integrate the second one between $x = \frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.

So the second integral should be,

$ \displaystyle 2 \int_{1/3}^{1/2} \int_{0}^{ \sqrt {3x-1}} dy ~dx$

That gives you $A = A_1 - A_2 = \frac{2}{3 \sqrt2} - \frac{2}{9\sqrt2} = \frac{2 \sqrt2}{9}$

[image]

Also note that you can directly integrate if you go with respect to $dx$ first. Keep the equations in the form $y^2 = x$ and $y^2 = 3x - 1 \implies x = \frac{y^2+1}{3} ~$.

At intersection $y^2 = x = 3x - 1 \implies x = \frac{1}{2}, y = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$

So the integral to find area between the curves is,

$\displaystyle \int_{- 1/\sqrt2}^{1/\sqrt2} \int_{y^2}^{ (y^2+1) / 3} ~ dx ~dy$

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation

Comment: If you fix your working for the second one, the answer matches. Please see my latest edit.

Comment: Thank you. So the method you mentioned, about integrating directly with respect $dx$, can I apply it for all situations of finding area between curves? I ask because I searched online and the only method they mentioned was the way I tried solving above i.e $\int F(x) - G(x))$

Comment: It depends on how the curves intersect. Sometimes integrating in one order is easier than the other. In this case you can see that all horizontal strips (at any $y$) are between two curves. That is why you can set up in one integral.

Comment: @DBZrasengan16 given you are new to the site, letting you know if you do not already know. If any of the answers helped you, you could consider accepting though it is not necessary. If there are multiple answers, you will have to choose one. While you can upvote multiple answers, you can accept only one answer. If you do not know how to accept, this link may help - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer/3287#3287

Answer (score 1):

I would integrate with respect to y.

$x = y^2\\
x = \frac {y^2}{3} + \frac 13$

The curves intersect at $(\frac 12, \frac {\sqrt {2}}{2})$ and $(\frac 12, -\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2})$

$\int_{-\frac {\sqrt {2}}{2}}^{\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}} \frac {y^2}{3} + \frac 13 - y^2\ dy$

Comment: Thank you. I was able to integrate and get the answer.